# Thunderbird scripting

Tags: scripting, thunderbird

I need to process a number of messages in my Thunderbird.app (Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Intel Core 2 Duo), delete a few based on some criteria, export some others, move a small part of them to a special folder and create a filing hierarchy to go with it all - programmatically.

With Outlook I used to enjoy VBScript + the COM object model: it would do all of the above simply and intuitively.

What can I use to achieve the same with Thunderbird?

If multiple options are available, here are my current preferences in terms of languages (although I can adapt to most things): Python, C++, AppleScript, PHP, Perl, Bash, ...

If I need to move to a Windows box to use .NET and the like, I can (yet I'd imaging the most popular bindings come from the open-source world?!) If there was a command-line tool that did what I need, I'd use that! (thunderbird.sh show messages; thunderbird.sh create folder X as child of folder Y;)

Answer (score 10):

You can develop Thunderbird extensions in a similar way to Firefox extensions in XUL and Javascript.

Try [this tutorial.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension)

> This tutorial will introduce you to the components of a Thunderbird extension and will show you how to build your own.

Comment: The one problem with this is that XUL/JS extensions are scripting entirely inside TB and with it's UI. I suspect the original poster meant being able to script it from the outside - so other apps on his apple desktop can perform TB actions - like prep a mail based on a PDF from a print workflow.

Comment: Or maybe not - I knew what I was looking for - but I needed to rtfq, the OP means automation purely inside TB - in which case this is the correct answer.

Comment: The link in this answer is outdated; see my answer below for the current way to go, or go directly to https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/about-add-ons

Answer (score 4):

You could also look at [the tbscript plugin](http://code.google.com/p/tbscript-plugin/), although it does have external dependencies - it uses Python.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial linked to in [the most popular answer as of today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3096203/4962868) still works, but is outdated.

For current versions of Thunderbird, documentation is at https://developer.thunderbird.net. This has an [add-on page](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/about-add-ons) that comes with a [tutorial](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-on-examples/hello-world-add-on) for developing a "Hello World" MailExtension.

The [MailExtension API](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/) is new for Thunderbird 68 (although some parts were published for earlier versions) and allows one to write JavaScript to e.g. handle messages.

Answer (score -3):

If you need a general purpose GUI scripting solution, try [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), it's very calable.